# invoke web request with invoke command dont work

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a PowerShell script to get an output from a remote computer using winrm . I basically run a invoke web request command in invoke-command. but the output I get is different from when I run the same code on the remote computer, any help would be appreciated. below is the example of the code snippet :

```
$url = "https://yahoo/finance"

$s = (New-PSSession -ComputerName computername -Credential domain\abcd) 
$result = Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {$response  = try { Invoke-WebRequest $url} catch { $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__ }
write-host $response
}

write-host $response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show us the error / problem, or at minimum explain it. You have issues in your code as well.

The $url is not right.

This ...

$url = "https://yahoo/finance"

Should be this...

$url = "https://www.yahoo.com/finance"

Write-Host clears the buffer, so, nothing will get returned after you use it. Avoid using it. You don't need it to write to the screen, just use the variable name.

This ...

$url = "https://yahoo/finance"

... will not work here

$result = Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {$response  = try { Invoke-WebRequest $url} catch { $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__ }

... Because that $url is a local variable, and cannot be used on a remote machine the way you are using it.

You need to set this local variable to be available remotely. The requires doing the following...

> About Remote Variables
>
> LONG DESCRIPTION
>
> You can use variables in commands that you run on remote computers.
>   Simply assign a value to the variable and then use the variable in
>   place of the value.
>
> By default, the variables in remote commands are assumed to be defined
>   in the session in which the command runs. You can also use variables
>   that are defined in the local session, but you must identify them as
>   local variables in the command.
>
> USING LOCAL VARIABLES
>
> You can also use local variables in remote commands, but you must
>   indicate that the variable is defined in the local session.
>
> Beginning in Windows PowerShell 3.0, you can use the Using scope
>   modifier to identify a local variable in a remote command.
>
> The syntax of Using is as follows:

```
$Using:<VariableName>

$ps = "Windows PowerShell"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName S1 -ScriptBlock {
  Get-WinEvent -LogName $Using:ps
}
```

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-5.1
>
> Access Local Variables in a Remote Session with PowerShell
>
> Occasionally I’ll come across a system with PowerShell version 2.0 on
>   it that I need to run a remote command against which needs access to
>   local variables. I can never remember how to accomplish that task so I
>   thought I would write a blog about it as a reminder for myself and
>   others who may find themselves in the same scenario.
>
> http://mikefrobbins.com/2017/11/09/access-local-variables-in-a-remote-session-with-powershell

You've also way over complicated this. A New-PSSession is not required to use Invoke-Command. You can just use the -computername parameter.
You only need a session, if you need a long term/extended connection to the remote host or you need to proxy the cmdlets from that remote host to your machine.

Comment: Thank you ! I was able to get it working using the remote variable syntax. The URL was just an example . I was not using the exact url. i also used invoke-command with computer name as per your suggestion.